# Mist Wallet Synch Stuck - Not coder/geek

Tags: mist, synchronization, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I too have the 'synch stuck' syndrome suffered by many others. I don't think I've ever been this frustrated but am trying to be patient. After 12-24 hours I get stuck around 2.4m block after multiple tries. Tried to access my Mist wallet after a long time since last successful access and now can't get it to synch. Running Win 10. Did some searching and found the youtube video by IMineBlocks "How to use Ethereum Mist wallet with Parity intead of geth." The Parity release was 1.3.3 at the time of the video. The latest release is 1.6.8. I followed the instructions and when I executed the Parity shortcut the window monitor opened, printed out a few lines very quickly and the then window shuts suddenly. I tried loading previous versions of Parity with the same or worse result. The windows shuts so quickly that I can't read what the few lines print.

I have a few questions:
1- Am I destined to never be able to access the ETH in my wallet, ie is it lost forever
2- What does the 'Skip Peer Search' mean? When I click on it, I can see my wallet but can't do anything with it, eg. can't 'SEND' ETH...
3- Any suggestions where I can go from here.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: another question: how do I find out what version of Mist wallet I have and how do I safely install the latest version? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pointless to say that is a very unpleasant problem of many users. I had the same problem especially with the final 200 blocks in which it stops forever.
Try to change the internet time to "time.nist.gov".
Control panel--> Clock,Language...--> Date and time--> Internet time. Before that i run the wallet i run geth.
I' ve done it yesterday.
For me it worked (it finish all the block and finally i can see my balance), but after some times is stuck again on the last blocks (180) for much time. Now is slowly proceeding. If you know someone trusted you can give him the key and transfer the ethereum on another wallet like kracken.